# Unable to discover NUnit test case

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm trying use Nunit to test my simple program, but I dont know why it cannot discover my test cases... Compile result is pass

Here are my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class FizzBuzz
    {
        public static string TestTarget(int parameters)
        {
            return parameters.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class FizzBuzzTest
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class fizzBuzzTest
        {
            [Test]
            public void TestCase1()
            {
                Assert.That(FizzBuzz.TestTarget(1), Is.EqualTo("1222"));

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the nested class is the problem.  Pull `fizzBuzzTest` out of `FizzBuzzTest`.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk thanks for ur answer, do you mean delete "class FizzBuzzTest" ?

Comment: You need to install NUnit adapter 3.0 for Nunit 3.0, or NUnit adapter 2 for Nunit 2.* versions.

Comment: @JackHughes just tried this example and it works without public.

Comment: @Valentin I can not find NUint3 by using search online but only NUint2. Should I install in here? [link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d)

Comment: @himaChen Where are you looking? use `Tools -> Extensions and Update -> Online`

Comment: @Valentin wow, it is work!!!  so much thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `Nunit 3.*` you need to install `NUnit3 Test Adapter`. 
For `Nunit 2.*` - `NUnit Test Adapter`.

In Visual Studio go to `Tools -> Extensions and Update -> Online` and find needed adapter.